Identify IC with marking CB=EB
Can anyone help me identify this component and where I can find a replacement?


Identify questions are OK. It's could be some switch mode controller or regulator as there is a huge inductor connected to it. However, asking where to buy replacement is off-topic, as well as repair questions without understanding of the circuit.

Please post a photo with better resolution.

The part is likely Richtek RT8058GQW, which is a Step-Down DC-DC converter.
This is the pinout from the datasheet which seems to match up with your circuit - the trhee pins for the inductor on 13-15, feedback on pin 4, and power rail on 9-12.


While the datasheet doesn't show the marking codes, searching around for QFN-16 CB= finds several chinese retailers showing photographs of this part number with that marking. The CB= is the part identifier and the last two letters and second line will probably be date and lot information.

Image Source
Replacements can be sourced from a number of distributors, just search for the product code.

Not if worth adding a picture from LCSC Richtek Tech RT8058GQW. The LCSC site is useful for such identification questions as they tend to have a picture of the actual device which helps to confirm the marking style.

@ChesterGillon aye, was just looking around to see if I could find one with the same date code, but the LCSC one will do. Found various numbers including EC and BE, so last digits are definitely some sort of date code.
